# Generate multiple x-y plots from the same data frame in the same plot using ggplot2 in R using a loop and display corresponding legend

Tags: r, loops, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have a data frame which I generated using the following piece of code,

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- x^3
z <- y-20
s <- z/3
t <- s*6
q <- s*y
x1 <- cbind(x,y,z,s,t,q)
x1 <- data.frame(x1)
```

The data frame x1 thus has the following data,

```
    x    y   z          s    t             q
1   1    1 -19  -6.333333  -38     -6.333333
2   2    8 -12  -4.000000  -24    -32.000000
3   3   27   7   2.333333   14     63.000000
4   4   64  44  14.666667   88    938.666667
5   5  125 105  35.000000  210   4375.000000
6   6  216 196  65.333333  392  14112.000000
7   7  343 323 107.666667  646  36929.666667
8   8  512 492 164.000000  984  83968.000000
9   9  729 709 236.333333 1418 172287.000000
10 10 1000 980 326.666667 1960 326666.666667
```

Now I want to plot columns x vs y, z vs s and t vs q in the same plot, so for this I use the following code,

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = x1, aes(x = x1[,1], y = x1[,2], color = "red")) +
  geom_line(data = x1, aes(x = x1[,3], y = x1[,4], color = "blue"))  +
  geom_line(data = x1, aes(x = x1[,5], y = x1[,6], color = "green"))  +
  xlab('x') +
  ylab('y')
```

While the above piece of code works fine for a data frame of just 6 columns, I would like to perform the same operation for a data frame with many number of columns. For example if there are 20 columns in a data frame, there should be one single plot generated containing plot of col 1 vs 2, col 3 vs 4, col 5 vs 6 and so on until col 19 vs 20. To do this I use this following piece of code,

```
p <- ggplot() +   geom_line(data = x1, aes(x = x1[,1], y = x1[,2], color = "red")) + xlab('x') + ylab('y')
ctr <- 1
for (iz in seq(3, ncol(x1), by = 2))
{
p$ctr <- p + geom_line(data = x1, aes(x = x1[,iz], y = x1[,iz+1], color = "green"))
ctr <- ctr+1
}
```

So the plots should be layered incrementally and the last object should contain the entire plot. Using the above code the plot gets overwritten every time when the loop runs, could some one point out how to capture the full data. I would like to display a legend for each of the plot as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop if you put your data into the right format. You can create a long data frame based on your original data frame.

```
x1_long <- data.frame(x = unlist(x1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]),
                      y = unlist(x1[c(FALSE, TRUE)]),
                      ind = gl(ncol(x1) / 2, nrow(x1)))
```

Now, a single `geom_line` command is sufficient:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x1_long) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = ind))
```

[image]

(Note. The red line is plotted too but its values are quite small.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I tried it, but in the plot which I get only the first x vs y data is displayed, do you know why might that be.

Comment: the structure of my data frame is of x1 in the above code, I don't know for what reason the graph is not updating and showing the entire plot as you have demonstrated above. I can use `scale_y_log10()` for displaying the full data.

Comment: There are no non-numeric values, I have included the data frame now in my question.

Comment: yes I used your complete code, should be device be turned off and on for the data to refresh?

Comment: @Amm Oh, sorry, there was a small error in my code. See the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
ggplot() + 
  lapply(seq(1,ncol(x1),2),         # every second col index
         function(x){               # return the geom_line calls in a list
    geom_line(aes_string(x=x1[x],   # remember to use aes_string for x
                         y=x1[x+1]),                           # and y
              color=factor(x),                                 # then color
              size=2)                                          # and size
    }) +
  xlab('x') +  ylab('y')
```

[image]